# Disable the physical Silent Mode switch on iPhone SE 2020?

Tags: iphone, sound-volume

I keep missing calls because the Silent Mode hardware toggle (outside left edge) keeps flipping inadvertently.

Is there a way to disable that switch, to prevent my iPhone SE from ever going into silent mode?

When I need silence, I can simply shutdown the iPhone.

Comment: Not being flippant here, but have you considered a little bit of tape? Black elictrical tape or duct tape might work best. I have done it from time to time and it works. Especially if the phone is in a case.

Comment: My workaround turned out to be buying a case. The case is thick enough on the sides to make the silence switch recessed, deep enough to avoid bumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

> Is there a way to disable that switch, to prevent my iPhone SE from ever going into silent mode?

There is no way to disable the working of the physical silent switch.

## Flash for alerts

If you keep missing calls due to the switch inadvertently getting flipped, you *may* consider enabling **LED Flash for Alerts**, a setting that flashes the iPhone camera's flashlight for alerts.

This may help with catching your attention if the iPhone is on silent mode either intentionally or inadvertently.

In iOS 13, the setting can be enabled by going to Settings app → Accessibility → Audio/Visual → LED Flash for Alerts.

[image: iPhone Settings app - LED Flash for Alerts]

## Flash only in Silent Mode

While this setting has been around for a long while in iOS, an interesting enhancement to the setting introduced in iOS 13 is the ability to have your iPhone's LED flash only when it's in silent mode.

[image: iPhone Settings app - LED Flash for Alerts - Flash on Silent]

Comment: Another solution: Some phone cases are raised high enough to prevent accidentally hitting the switch.

Answer (score 3):

apply very little drop of cyanoacrylate glue on the button, I did that and it works great so far!

Comment: Potentially damaging the phone?

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a good answer.  A piece of Scotch tape worked fine - for about a week before the tape started to sag and the switch tuned off.  I already had a case but that wasn't stopping the switch from turning off.  I was thinking about epoxy but really didn't want an irreversible solution.  The switch itself sits in an oval shaped opening in the case with just enough of a gap to slide the switch up or down.  The size of the gap is roughly the diameter of a straight pin so I cut off a segment of the pin about 3/16" long and dropped it into the gap below the switch when it was on.  I then used a piece of Scotch tape over everything.  There is now no strain on the tape - it simply needs to keep the pin in place and, if needed, can be removed to restore the function.